# Raspberry Pi Debug Probe fails with `Error: Unknown flash device (ID 0x00ffffff)`

Tags: debug

I am trying to debug a custom rp2040b2 board with Winbond W25Q128JVSQ with the debug probe and am following the Raspberry Pi Debug Probe [tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/debug-probe.html). The board is intended to be similar to a Pico (for easier firmware programming), but with features specific to connecting with a keyboard matrix.

When I try and upload my first program to my custom board I get the following error. It is my suspicion that the W25Q128JVSQ is not being detected properly. After looking through the code, it appears to support the W25Q128JV. I also verified all the schematics and as expected the connection to the flash chip is standard serial SPI NOR FLASH wired to the rp2040. Any help would be appreciated!

```
sudo openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -c "adapter speed 5000" -c "program hello_serial.elf verify reset exit"
```

Result

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-g4d87f6d (2023-12-10-10:40)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : Hardware thread awareness created
Info : Hardware thread awareness created
adapter speed: 5000 kHz

Info : Using CMSIS-DAPv2 interface with VID:PID=0x2e8a:0x000c, serial=E6616407E33E4729
Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Atomic commands supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Test domain timer supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 2.0.0
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 0 SWDIO/TMS = 0 TDI = 0 TDO = 0 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 0
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 5000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x0bc12477, DLPIDR 0x00000001
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x0bc12477, DLPIDR 0x10000001
Info : [rp2040.core0] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [rp2040.core0] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : [rp2040.core1] Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : [rp2040.core1] target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for rp2040.core0 on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
[rp2040.core0] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ea msp: 0x20041f00
[rp2040.core1] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x000000ea msp: 0x20041f00
** Programming Started **
Error: Unknown flash device (ID 0x00ffffff)
Error: auto_probe failed
** Programming Failed **
shutdown command invoked
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double check your schematics. I had the same problem and found I had swapped QSPI_SD0 and QSPI_SD1. Your picture indicates the same...
Here is the reference to the official minimum schematic:
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/Minimal-KiCAD.zip

edit: I used JLCPCB and in their block for the W25Q128 the description for DO and D1 can be understood as IO0 and IO1 if that makes sense. [image]

Comment: Nice find, let me check this out in detail.